# Configurable Products with Soap API

Tags: magento-1.8, api, ce-1.8.1.0, soap

I'm trying to import some products from one shop to another. To reach my goal i need to create configurable products. Create simple products are fine, but create configurable products are a pain (because it isn't documented).

Can someone teach me in the right direction?

I found this links (but this didn't work):

- http://netzkollektiv.com/blog/configurable-products-mit-der-netzkollektiv-coreapi-extension-fur-magento/
- http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/04/20/magento-api-associate-simple-products-to-configurable-or-grouped-product/

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what/how your tried to create the configureable products? Do you get any specific error?

Comment: I don't get an error, the configured product is created but no products has been linked. And when i go to the admin page and want to edit this product, magento ask me which option i want to use.

Comment: So, which functions do you use and in which order? What do these functions return? I would be interested in the return value of your soap-call which assigns the product.

Comment: I created a gist, so you can show what i've written.
Maybe you find my bug.

https://gist.github.com/Baachi/86791f214fcc8c9fea56

Comment: hello, did you find any solution for the problem?

Comment: Yes, we use this [extension](http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/04/20/magento-api-associate-simple-products-to-configurable-or-grouped-product/). It is the best option to create configurable products (at least for us).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try an import module like [FastSimpleImport](http://avstudnitz.github.io/AvS_FastSimpleImport/)?

I haven't tried, but it seems to support configurable products. It is free and opensource, you should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This article on Adding Configurable Products via SOAP may give you an indication on areas which are lacking in Magento's documentation
http://netzkollektiv.com/blog/add-configurable-products-via-soapxml-rpc/

Comment: This article is based on a non-existant API method, catalog_product_type_configurable.assign

Comment: @barbazul It's only existent if you add the plugin from Netzkollektiv.